# Can FXSAVE be executed twice before an FXRSTOR?

Tags: c, assembly, linux-kernel, x86, x86-64

While hacking the Linux kernel, I noticed that it would execute an `FXSAVE` instruction before performing FPU related tasks. I understand that the `FXSAVE` instruction will save the FPU state to a destination in memory, which can be restored via a `FXRSTOR` instruction. My question is if I can execute `FXSAVE` twice before an `FXRSTOR` instruction is executed.

For example:

```
char fxsave_region1[512] __attribute__((aligned(16)));
char fxsave_region2[512] __attribute__((aligned(16)));

asm volatile(" fxsave; "::"m"(fxsave_region1));

/* miscellaneous floating point operations */

asm volatile(" fxsave; "::"m"(fxsave_region2)); /* will this work? */

/* some more miscellaneous floating point operations */

asm volatile(" fxrstor; "::"m"(fxsave_region2));

/* even more miscellaneous floating point operations */

asm volatile(" fxrstor; "::"m"(fxsave_region1));
```

Or is only one level of saving supported?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike `F(N)SAVE`, `FXSAVE` does not change the state of the FPU/MMX and SSE registers, so you can repeat it multiple times.

Comment: So the FPU state can change between the two `FXSAVE` instructions, resulting in two different FPU states saved to memory, which can then be restored independently at any time with their respective `FXRSTOR` instruction?